# If a|b and b|a, find the value of a in terms of b.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

If a|b and b|a, where a and b are integers and a≠0, find the value of a in terms of b.

Assume that b>0.

Comment: Hint: $a|b$ implies $a\leq b$...

Comment: ^That is false if we're dealing with possibly negative integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a|b \implies b=ak$ and $b|a \implies a=mb$.

Therefore that $$a=mb=mka \implies mk=1 \implies m=k=1 \text { or } m=k=-1  $$

So $a=\pm b$